# Influence of variables on duration time of a pump

Tags: categorical-encoding

I would really appreciate some help as I don't have a strong background on statistics.
I have duration time without failure data of compressors (Machines) for 3 brands, and I have for each of them:
- material type (categorical)
- location (categorical)
- capacity (numerical). 
I have data of 125 compressors of brand A, 149 of Brand B and 65 of Brand C (unpaired data).

Do you know which analysis I could apply in order to identify what variable (material type, location and capacity) is affecting more the duration time (the longer the duration time, the better)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a mixture of cagegorical an numerical predictors, a regression analysis would be adequate. You migh consider transforming the response (duration) to the log scale for instance, so you do not have problems with negative predicted durations.

If you use software such as R it will take care of the coding of categorical variables.

You migh also view your problem as one of survival analysis, but as you say you do not have much background in statistics I think regression will be adequate and serve your purposes well enough.